# Accepting Form-Data with Delete Request in Lumen API

Tags: laravel, api, http, lumen, http-method

I am having problem with accepting **form-data** request with **DELETE method** in lumen api.

I can successfully get form-data request when it sends through **POST method**.

But when I send data with :

```
Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
or
Content-Type : application/json
```

I am getting the data.

To be more clear -
As an example, If I want to delete a product with the id :
I would pass the id with body value such as -

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="5" />
```

In Controller :

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
{
   $id = $request->id;
}
```

My Route :

```
$router->delete('categories', ['uses' => '\ProductController@destroy']);
```

Is there any other configurations to make it work with **form-data request on delete method** ?

Answer (score 0):

Only `GET` and `POST` requests are supported when using form-data.

If you want to make a `PUT/PATCH/DELETE` request you have to add an hidden input with name `_method` and desired http verb for value.

Ex:

`<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">` for `DELETE` requests.

Comment: Well, that works on laravel to laravel or lumen, I am trying to make an API with lumen to allow every kind of form-data to the methods, while the front-end is built on angular 5, and I am testing my api with POSTMAN, where I can't give data with form-data in DELETE method